# Struggling with number regex match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match only numbers and spaces in my php regex but the following fails and I can't seem to understand why, can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong please?

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9\ ]$/';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression just describes one single character. You might want to add a [quantifier](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.repetition.php) like `+`:

```
'/^[0-9\ ]+$/'
```

This describes a string of one or more digits or space characters.

Comment: @Yacoby: Yes, you’re right. The space does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

........

```
$pattern = '/^[\d\ ]+$/';
```

Comment: There was before the edit. The downvote has now been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:

'/^[0-9\s]+$/'

\s stands for space char